# How can I make a RealmProxy[Object] and its corresponding [Object] equal?

Tags: android, realm

Ok, so I implemented Realm for my android App. The app is basically an accounting-shopping list hybrid where a user adds items he or she already purchased.

In my `Accounting` class, which holds the Realm database implementation, the method for adding an item returns an int to my main Activity to be used in `RecyclerAdapter.notifyItemInserted`.

Here's how the method is supposed to work

```
public int addItem(final Item latestItem) {
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    Number firstId = mRealm.where(Item.class).max("ID");
    int nextId = firstId != null ? firstId.intValue() + 1 : 0;
    Item firstItem = mRealm.where(Item.class)
            .equalTo("mName", latestItem.getName())
            .equalTo("mPrice", latestItem.getPrice())
            .findFirst();

    if (firstItem == null) {
        latestItem.setID(nextId);
        mRealm.copyToRealm(latestItem);
    } else  {
        firstItem.setCount(firstItem.getCount() +  latestItem.getCount());
    }
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
    updateItemList();

    int index = mItemList.indexOf(latestItem);
    return index;
```

The problem is the the index is `-1`, i.e the object doesn't exist in the List object I populate with the database objects as presented here:

```
private void updateItemList() {
    mItemList = mRealm.where(Item.class).findAllSorted("mPrice", Sort.DESCENDING);
}
```

I've tried manually retrieving the object from the database and it's shown as a `RealmProxyItem`. Testing for `equals()` returns false. Casting just throws `ClassCastException`.

What do I do to ensure that the `equals()` returns true?

EDIT: Here's my Realm model

**Item.java**

```
public class Item extends RealmObject{
@PrimaryKey
private int ID;

private String mName;
private double mPrice;
private int mCount;
private int mItemType;

public Item() {/** Required due to Realm **/ }

public Item(String mName, double mPrice, int count, int itemType) {
    this.mName = mName;
    this.mPrice = mPrice;
    this.mCount = count;
    this.mItemType = itemType;
    this.ID = 0;
}

 /**public Item(String mName, double mPrice, int count) {
    this(mName, mPrice, count, ItemType.NO_TYPE);
} **/

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return mPrice;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    mCount = count;
}

public int getItemType() {
    return mItemType;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

/** public ItemType getItemType() {
    return mItemType;
}  **/

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object == null) return false;
    else if (object.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;

    Item item = (Item) object;

    if (!item.getName().equals(this.getName())) return false;
    else if (item.getPrice() != this.getPrice()) return false;
    //else if (!item.getItemType().equals(this.getItemType())) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 17 * hash + this.mName.hashCode();
    hash = 17 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.mPrice) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.mPrice) >>> 32));
    return hash;
}

public void increaseCountBy(int amount) {
    mCount += amount;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your realm model?

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori Added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a primary key in your model i'd say change your `equals()` method to this :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object == null || !(object instanceof Item)) return false;
    Item item = (Item) object;

    return item.getID() == ID;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea  why, but your code worked. Thank you so friggin much!!!!

P.S. How DID the code work?  Did the ID check force the objects to match regardless of classes?

Comment: Ehm no actually the `indexOf()` method just calls the `equals()` method of the models in the list to check if they equal. If you don't override the `equals` method, java will by default compare memory references when you call it. Since the realm proxy model extends the model you can safe cast it to your model and then just check if the ID is the same. Your two models have the same id only if they represent the same item. Btw could you upvote my answer and accept it if it helped you? ^^

Comment: A  lready did! problem is m y rep is < 15 so it can't be seen. Sorry tho haha!

Comment: Also, my Item class did already have an overidden  `equals()` method. So maybe the ID check did force it?

Comment: no actually `object.getClass() != this.getClass()` returned false, because the classes of the proxys differ from the model. And also just a tip don't check name and price in these lines `if (!item.getName().equals(this.getName())) return false;
    else if (item.getPrice() != this.getPrice()) return false;` if you already have an ID. the ID is unique so it makes much more sense to compare id's.